# How to install go and goisntall on ubuntu for doozer install

Tags: ubuntu, go

I am using ubuntu 10.04 and 12.04.

I am tryig to install doozer and doozed and I am having a hard time dealing with go isntall.  I will need to make a chef recipe for the install.

The directions for installing doozer as follows:

```
goinstall github.com/ha/doozer
```

How to I get goinstall?

EDIT: Using Go 1.0.2 and `go install`, I get the following output:

```
github.com/ha/doozer
# github.com/ha/doozer
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozer/conn.go:184: cannot use &t.req (type *request) as type proto.Message in function argument:
    *request does not implement proto.Message (missing ProtoMessage method)
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozer/conn.go:198: cannot use &r (type *response) as type proto.Message in function argument:
    *response does not implement proto.Message (missing ProtoMessage method)
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozer/conn.go:294: undefined: proto.GetInt64
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozer/conn.go:326: undefined: proto.GetInt64
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozer/conn.go:412: undefined: proto.GetInt32
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozer/conn.go:412: undefined: proto.GetInt64
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozer/err.go:33: cannot call non-function proto.GetString (type struct {})
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozer/msg.pb.go:127: cannot use this (type *request) as type proto.Message in function argument:
    *request does not implement proto.Message (missing ProtoMessage method)
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozer/msg.pb.go:142: cannot use this (type *response) as type proto.Message in function argument:
    *response does not implement proto.Message (missing ProtoMessage method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `doozer` and `doozerd` packages use an old, obsolete version of Go. For the current version, Go 1, get the source code:

```
go get -v github.com/ha/doozer

go get -v github.com/ha/doozerd
```

Upgrade the source code to Go 1 and then use `go install`:

```
go install -v github.com/ha/doozer

go install -v github.com/ha/doozerd
```

Also, `pretty.go` has been renamed to [`pretty`](https://github.com/kr/pretty):

See [Command go](http://golang.org/cmd/go/).

Comment: Hi, I installed go1.0.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz. I get this error.  go install -v github.com/ha/doozerd
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/ha/doozer/conn.go:7:2: no Go source files in /usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/kr/pretty.go

Comment: I installed pretty btw. go install -v github.com/kr/pretty

Comment: Since package `pretty.go` has been renamed to `pretty`, change line 7 of `conn.go` from `"github.com/kr/pretty.go"`to `"github.com/kr/pretty"`.

Comment: As I've said before, the doozer and doozerd packages use an old, obsolete version of Go. To eliminate the package compile errors, upgrade the sources for the doozer and doozerd packages to Go 1. For help in doing this, there's a doozer group at: http://groups.google.com/group/doozer

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference (go to prepare)

```
$ cd /var/tmp
$ wget http://go.googlecode.com/files/go1.0.2.linux-386.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz go1...tar.gz
$ export GOROOT=/var/tmp/go
$ export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
$ go
Go is a tool for managing Go source code.

Usage:

    go command [arguments]

The commands are:

    build       compile packages and dependencies
    clean       remove object files
    doc         run godoc on package sources
    env         print Go environment information
    fix         run go tool fix on packages
    fmt         run gofmt on package sources
    get         download and install packages and dependencies
    install     compile and install packages and dependencies
    list        list packages
    run         compile and run Go program
    test        test packages
    tool        run specified go tool
    version     print Go version
    vet         run go tool vet on packages

Use "go help [command]" for more information about a command.

Additional help topics:

    gopath      GOPATH environment variable
    packages    description of package lists
    remote      remote import path syntax
    testflag    description of testing flags
    testfunc    description of testing functions

Use "go help [topic]" for more information about that topic.
```